# Show Mysql result with C in Gtktreeview

Tags: mysql, gtk

I try to use GtktreeView to show results of mysql query in C with following code which is called from change handler of gtkentry for getting "search as you type" efect:

```
...
    result = mysql_store_result(conn);
if (result)
{
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {
    gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, cID, row[0],
                                     cCity, row[1],
                                     cState, row[2],
                                     cPop, atoi(row[3]),
                                     cLast, "", -1);
   }
}
etc...
```

Problem is that result can contain much data, to few thousand rows and while mysql is fast enough, that amount of data makes GtkTreeView unacceptable slow (much slower than typing and often shock computer). When I put LIMIT 20 in query this code works OK but then only first 20 rows of matched data are achievable. I think this is so slow because of all redrawing of gtktreeview is active.
In some toolkits it is possible to turn of all refreshes while list loads and then simple show results when finish with loading. Is something like that possible in GtkTreeView?

Or can I do something else? Like put this function in thread?
Or any other solution?

Thanks for advice in advanced!

Comment: Why not try [`GtkEntryCompletion`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEntryCompletion.html) instead of creating your own TreeView?

Comment: Why not? But I never try that. Can you point me to any basic workable example of using GtkEntryCompletion in similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what your requirement is. Unfortunenately I have no prior experience with mysql either. But regarding using `GtkEntryCompletion` with `GtkEntry` to have a "search as you type" effect, you have to create a [`GtkEntryCompletion`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEntryCompletion.html) and set it to `GtkEntry`. Then you can set a model to entry completion from which completion data is picked. Here is a sample code based on gtk-demo source & coding.debuntu.org code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

static gboolean
on_match_select(GtkEntryCompletion *widget, GtkTreeModel *model,GtkTreeIter *iter, gpointer user_data)
{
    GValue value = {0, };
    GValue id = {0, };
    gtk_tree_model_get_value(model, iter, 1, &value);
    gtk_tree_model_get_value(model, iter, 0, &id);
    fprintf(stdout, "You have selected value=\"%s\" with id = %d\n",
        g_value_get_string(&value),
        g_value_get_int(&id));
    g_value_unset(&value);
    g_value_unset(&id);

    return FALSE;
}

/* Creates a tree model containing the completions */
static GtkTreeModel *
create_completion_model (void)
{
    GtkListStore *store;
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    int id = 0;
    char buffer[1024]={0,};

    store = gtk_list_store_new (2, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_STRING);

    /* Here we add the data to be shown for completion */
    /* Add 10000 strings */
    for(id = 0; id < 10000; id++)
    {
        if(id%2)
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer -1, "homer #%d with %d", id/2, id);
        else
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer -1, "marge #%d with %d", id/2, id);

        gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
        gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter, 0, id, 1, buffer, -1);
    }
    return GTK_TREE_MODEL (store);
}


int main (void)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkEntryCompletion *completion;
    GtkTreeModel *completion_model;

    gtk_init (NULL, NULL);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Sample entry completion");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 5);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 5);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    label = gtk_label_new (NULL);
    gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (label),
                        "Completion demo, try writing <b>homer/marge #...</b>; replace ... by a number b/w 0 &amp; 9999.");

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    /* Create our entry */
    entry = gtk_entry_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), entry, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    /* Create the completion object */
    completion = gtk_entry_completion_new ();

    /* Assign the completion to the entry */
    gtk_entry_set_completion (GTK_ENTRY (entry), completion);
    g_object_unref (completion);

    /* Create a tree model and use it as the completion model */
    completion_model = create_completion_model ();
    gtk_entry_completion_set_model (completion, completion_model);
    /* Connect callback for match selection */
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (completion), "match-selected", G_CALLBACK (on_match_select), NULL);
    g_object_unref (completion_model);

    /* Use model column 1 (i.e. 2nd column) as the text column */
    /* Model currently used has int (id) in 1st column & string (data) in 2nd column */
    gtk_entry_completion_set_text_column (completion, 1);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully this is a bit faster than you current method.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Here is mysql just data source (like for loop) so this example is very useful, thank you. And it is faster because of creating model without showing data immediately. In my case not fully applicable because it searches only from beginning but surely useful for some options. Anyway, is here some place where such examples for Gtk2 can be downloaded?

Comment: Additionally, I found interesting usage of entry completion in my search but I cannot force matched suggestions list to allways open to UP (over) dirrection. Is this possible to do?

Comment: @user973238: I am sorry, I don't understand. You mean the completion drop down list show above your entry?

Comment: Huh, yes, gown I have some useful funcions and I would like "drop up" list :) To be opened always at top of entry, not at bottom.

Comment: @user973238: I think it displays the list where the space is available to show... I will have to check if you can force it to show up always

Comment: Yes, this is true. Please try when you catch some time!